# I want to transfer 1 devops card to another account

Tags: azure-devops, devops

When I am trying to export data from old devops it is generating CSV file for records, But I need images also to import into new account.

I have search a lot but did'nt get any success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### If you want to migrate work items with images from one project to another project in **the same organization**:

You just need to **reserve work item id column when exporting CSV**. When importing within the same organization, Azure DevOps can identify work items by id and migrates "the whole work item" including images in rich-text fields and attachments.

Note that work items that are migrated in this way will disappear in the old project while it is saved to the new project.

#### If you want to migrate work items **from one organization to another organization**:

**If your image is in rich-text fields, such as "Discription", "Acceptance Criteria", ...**

Before exporting, you need to click "Column options" and

1. remove the "ID" column.
2. add all the column you need to migrate. Please note that you cannot add automatically calculated fields such as "Comment Count".

After that, you can export the CSV file and import it to the new organization. You will find that the formatting and images in the rich-text fields are preserved.

This is because the rich-text fields are stored in the CSV file using HTML format.

**If your images are in attachments**

It is not supported to migrate attachments using built-in exporting and importing feature. You need to update the attachments manually or through the [REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1).

Also, there are some extensions, such as [Migration Tools for Azure DevOps](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=nkdagility.vsts-sync-migration) and [vsts-work-item-migrator](https://github.com/microsoft/vsts-work-item-migrator) can help you migrate attachments.

Through excel, you can add attachments in CSV files as well. Please check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/backlogs/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process#add-attachments) for detailed information.